# How can I append zeroes in place of empty spaces after the decimal in a number?

Tags: java, padding

This is the question and I am stuck that how can I append zeroes in place of empty spaces after the decimal in java.
[enter link description here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem)

Comment: He wants trailing zeroes, not leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string formatter can do it.

```
 String s = String.format("%.30f", 1.23);
```

or

```
 System.out.printf("%.30f %n", 1.23);
```

Those examples give you 30 places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

A `java.text.DecimalFormat` instance can do this for you, here is an example:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00000").format(1.23);    // => 1.23000
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00000").format(.987643); // => 0.98764
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DecimalFormat#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)) to do so.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define the formatter
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");

        // Tests
        System.out.println(formatter.format(0.3));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(123.3));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(0.335));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(0.0));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(1.0));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.300000
123.300000
0.335000
0.000000
1.000000
```